# React Native yarn android works fine but ./gradlew assembleRelease build failing after updating compileSdkVersion & targetSdkVersion to 31

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to update one of my old project in which our build.gradle file is below.
Prior to update it was working fine and generated apk also works fine but now it is throwing this error **Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.

> Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1**

**yarn android is working fine and app is building successfully**

**"react-native": "^0.66.5"**

```
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())


buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
        androidXCore = "1.7.0" 
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1")
    
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
     mavenCentral()
     google()
     jcenter()
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        exclusiveContent {
           filter {
               includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
           }
           forRepository {
               maven {
                   url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
               }
           }
       }
    }
}
allprojects {
     configurations.all {
          resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
          }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

And my **app/build.gradle** is

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.10, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.everywhereagents"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 13
        versionName "1.0.12"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    def work_version = "2.6.0"
        // Force WorkManager 2.6.0 for transitive dependency
        implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version") {
            force = true
        }
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile project(":react-native-shared-preferences")

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

**Error I am getting**

```
> Task :lottie-react-native:bundleReleaseAar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :lottie-react-native:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-callkeep:bundleReleaseAar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-callkeep:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_masked-view:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :lottie-react-native:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_netinfo:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-callkeep:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-fs:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-document-picker:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-callkeep:verifyReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-callkeep:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-fs:verifyReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_masked-view:verifyReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_netinfo:verifyReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-document-picker:verifyReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-document-picker:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_netinfo:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-geolocation-service:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_masked-view:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-fs:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-get-random-values:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:verifyReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-image-picker:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-incall-manager:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :lottie-react-native:verifyReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :lottie-react-native:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-linear-gradient:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-maps:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-image-picker:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-image-picker:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-image-picker:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-incall-manager:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:syncReleaseLibJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-incall-manager:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-incall-manager:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:bundleReleaseAar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-incall-manager:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-incall-manager:syncReleaseLibJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-maps:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-incall-manager:bundleReleaseAar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-incall-manager:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-image-picker:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-geolocation-service:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-maps:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-get-random-values:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-image-picker:syncReleaseLibJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-maps:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-linear-gradient:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-linear-gradient:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-geolocation-service:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-get-random-values:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-maps:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-geolocation-service:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-image-picker:bundleReleaseAar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-linear-gradient:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-image-picker:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-get-random-values:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-geolocation-service:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-maps:syncReleaseLibJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-geolocation-service:syncReleaseLibJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-linear-gradient:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-linear-gradient:syncReleaseLibJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-maps:bundleReleaseAar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-maps:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-get-random-values:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-linear-gradient:bundleReleaseAar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-linear-gradient:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-geolocation-service:bundleReleaseAar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-geolocation-service:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-incall-manager:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-linear-gradient:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-incall-manager:verifyReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-incall-manager:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-onesignal:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-get-random-values:syncReleaseLibJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-get-random-values:bundleReleaseAar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-get-random-values:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-linear-gradient:verifyReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-linear-gradient:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-pager-view:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:verifyReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-permissions:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-pager-view:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-permissions:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-permissions:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-permissions:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-onesignal:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-pager-view:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-permissions:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-permissions:syncReleaseLibJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-image-picker:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-onesignal:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-permissions:bundleReleaseAar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-permissions:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-pager-view:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-pager-view:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-onesignal:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-get-random-values:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-maps:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-onesignal:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-image-picker:verifyReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-image-picker:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-reanimated:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-onesignal:syncReleaseLibJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-onesignal:bundleReleaseAar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-onesignal:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-pager-view:syncReleaseLibJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-pager-view:bundleReleaseAar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-pager-view:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-reanimated:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-permissions:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-reanimated:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-reanimated:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-reanimated:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-reanimated:syncReleaseLibJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-permissions:verifyReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-permissions:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-get-random-values:verifyReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-get-random-values:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-screens:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-screens:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-screens:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-screens:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-screens:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-screens:syncReleaseLibJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-screens:bundleReleaseAar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:syncReleaseLibJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:bundleReleaseAar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-pager-view:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-reanimated:bundleReleaseAar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-reanimated:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-geolocation-service:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-maps:verifyReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-maps:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-pager-view:verifyReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-pager-view:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-screens:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-onesignal:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-splash-screen:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-geolocation-service:verifyReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-geolocation-service:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-svg:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-splash-screen:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-svg:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-shared-preferences:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-splash-screen:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-reanimated:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-splash-screen:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-splash-screen:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-shared-preferences:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-splash-screen:syncReleaseLibJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-shared-preferences:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-splash-screen:bundleReleaseAar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-splash-screen:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-shared-preferences:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-shared-preferences:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-shared-preferences:syncReleaseLibJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-reanimated:verifyReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-reanimated:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-vector-icons:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-svg:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-svg:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-shared-preferences:bundleReleaseAar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-shared-preferences:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-vector-icons:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-svg:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:verifyReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-svg:syncReleaseLibJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-svg:bundleReleaseAar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-svg:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-vector-icons:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-vector-icons:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-onesignal:verifyReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-onesignal:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-vector-icons:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-webrtc:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-vector-icons:syncReleaseLibJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-vector-icons:bundleReleaseAar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-vector-icons:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-splash-screen:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-screens:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-shared-preferences:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-webrtc:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-svg:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-splash-screen:verifyReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-splash-screen:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-webrtc:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-webrtc:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-webrtc:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-shared-preferences:verifyReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-shared-preferences:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-svg:verifyReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-svg:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-webrtc:syncReleaseLibJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-vector-icons:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-webrtc:bundleReleaseAar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-webrtc:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-screens:verifyReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-screens:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-vector-icons:verifyReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-vector-icons:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-webrtc:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-webrtc:verifyReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-webrtc:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
warning: the transform cache was reset.
                    Welcome to Metro!
              Fast - Scalable - Integrated


Failed to construct transformer:  Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at stableHash (/Users/dev/Desktop/MyProject/node_modules/metro-cache/src/stableHash.js:19:8)
    at Object.getCacheKey (/Users/dev/Desktop/MyProject/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:593:7)
    at getTransformCacheKey (/Users/dev/Desktop/MyProject/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/getTransformCacheKey.js:24:19)
    at new Transformer (/Users/dev/Desktop/MyProject/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:48:9)
    at /Users/dev/Desktop/MyProject/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:22:29 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile').
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile')
    at Bundler.transformFile (/Users/dev/Desktop/MyProject/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:48:30)
    at async Object.transform (/Users/dev/Desktop/MyProject/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:101:12)
    at async processModule (/Users/dev/Desktop/MyProject/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:137:18)
    at async traverseDependenciesForSingleFile (/Users/dev/Desktop/MyProject/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:131:3)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async initialTraverseDependencies (/Users/dev/Desktop/MyProject/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:114:3)
    at async DeltaCalculator._getChangedDependencies (/Users/dev/Desktop/MyProject/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/DeltaCalculator.js:164:25)
    at async DeltaCalculator.getDelta (/Users/dev/Desktop/MyProject/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/DeltaCalculator.js:94:16)
    at async DeltaBundler.buildGraph (/Users/dev/Desktop/MyProject/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler.js:50:5)
    at async IncrementalBundler.buildGraphForEntries (/Users/dev/Desktop/MyProject/node_modules/metro/src/IncrementalBundler.js:80:19)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
> Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 30s
684 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 681 up-to-date
```

Comment: have you tried creating by this command in your android ? ./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets

Comment: Thankyou @Mahammad Momin I tried that but when app gets installed on real device it gets crashed.

Thanahal Brother Your are always saviour that works actually I am having another new latest project and i have used nvm use 18.11.0 for that. and problem was lying actually there

Answer (score 1):

you need to follow below step

```
1. cd android && ./gradlew clean
2. ./gradlew bundleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
3. cd .. && npx react-native run-android --variant=release
```

hope it's working fine

Comment: Mine problem was in node version I tuned 16.17.0 from 18.11.0 and that works perfectly